# Increase MATLAB's integral speed

Tags: matlab

I'm implementing the Bates filter (Maximum Likelihood Estimation
of Latent Affine Processes, 2006) on MATLAB (a lot of inverse FT oscillatory integrals) and already using saddle point theory to make the integrand numerically efficient as possible.

Actually, MATLAB's integral command seems unbeatable (even compared to quadgk) but I would like to compute them faster.

Is there any way to increase it's speed? I've been reading some stuff about MEX but haven't found this command on C++.

Thanks in advance !